# Conditionally appending AND to where clause in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched all over and find questions on conditional `where clauses` but nothing about conditionally appending an `and` piece onto the `where clause`. I'm not a sql/database person, I'm from another `IT` area who has been thrown into a "go try to fix it" problem today because our regular database people are gone. I have basic programming concepts and knowledge but `sql` is just a foreign animal to me.

I have a simple:

```
SELECT abc FROM table WHERE sdate=@somedt
```

But I need it to add:

```
AND otherdt=@otherdt
```

but only if the `@otherdt` is not null. If it is null I don't want to add the `AND` part at all. I've tried a few ways to do it but it keeps giving me an error. Any help is appreciated. This was my last unsuccessful try:

```
SELECT abc FROM table 
WHERE sdate=@somedt
IF @otherdt IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
AND otherdt=@otherdt
END
```

Comment: Ahh THANK YOU shawnt00 and ibiza that worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT abc FROM table 
WHERE sdate = @somedt AND (@otherdt IS NULL OR otherdt = @otherdt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this condition :

```
SELECT abc FROM table 
WHERE sdate=@somedt AND (@otherdt IS NULL OR otherdt = @otherdt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@somedt DATETIME 
       ,@otherdt DATETIME

SET @Sql = N' SELECT abc 
              FROM table 
              WHERE sdate = @somedt '
        + CASE WHEN  @otherdt IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND otherdt = @otherdt'
             ELSE N'' END

Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                  ,N'@somedt DATETIME , @otherdt DATETIME'
                  ,@somedt
                  ,@otherdt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`, which in many cases performs better than `OR` queries.

```
SELECT abc FROM table
WHERE sdate=@somedt AND @otherdt IS NULL
UNION
SELECT abc FROM table
WHERE sdate=@somedt AND otherdt = @otherdt
```